# sed (bash) has different interpretation of regex than any other tool?

Tags: regex, sed

I am using ***sed*** to clean up a 100MB text file containing word frequencies.

To test my work I work with this short sample:

```
86501.522305    .
30876.406478    yes
15806.203945    no
15397.078939    what
9461.059877     8
10526.408684    ,
```

The whitespace is a single tab character.
My goal is to empty all rows with "non-words", i.e line 1, 5 and 6.

My regex

```
^\S*?\t[\W\d]+$
```

works fine when testing on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) and in Notepad++, but my sed command

```
sed -ri 's/^\S*?\t[\W\d]+$//g' sample.txt
```

keeps the file completely unaltered (except for the file metadata).

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this weird behaviour?

I have checked the docs for *extended regular expressions* and tried escaping all kinds of characters, but with no success.

Comment: Regex interpreters can and do vary between different languages and implementations. That's why a lot of online regex evaluators let you pick.

Comment: `'s/^[^[:space:]]*\t[^[:alpha:]_]+$//'` should work. If you need  to remove whole lines use `'/^[^[:space:]]*\t[^[:alpha:]_]+$/d'`.

Comment: The problem is with `[\W\d]`.

Comment: ... and with `*?` (and `\S` if `-r` didn't indicate GNU sed).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! With your and Ed Morton's help I could advance my understanding of how much I don't know about Regex. And solve my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing weird about seds behavior, you just misunderstood that there are multiple different flavors of regexp and multiple tools that support some/all of them in different ways with different options and different caveats.

sed by default supports POSIX BREs while your regexp contains a PCRE (not an ERE) with a bunch of non-POSIX extensions. GNU and OSX/BSD sed support EREs with the -E argument (older GNU seds use -r) and GNU sed supports some extensions - I'd expect \S and maybe \W to work but not \d. No sed supports PCREs.

FWIW I'd use awk for this for clarity, efficiency, portability, etc.:

```
$ awk '{print ($NF ~ /[[:alnum:]_]/ ? $0 : "")}' file | cat -n
     1
     2  30876.406478    yes
     3  15806.203945    no
     4  15397.078939    what
     5  9461.059877     8
     6
```

That will work with any awk in any shell on every UNIX box. The `| cat -n` is just to show that the lines were emptied rather than deleted.

Comment: Thank you for giving me that thorough explanation! I was aware of regex-flavors and thought I was "on the safe side" by trying them all. I'll change to awk, as you suggested, but still wish that these caveats would not appear so unexpectedly. I'm a frequent user of regex-es, but until now I was lucky that implementations never varied between programs and that they stated their flavor explicitly.

Comment: You're welcome. FWIW I've never come across 2 tools that had the same regexp implementations, they all have their own idiosyncrasies. Maybe that's just a UNIX thing, idk.

Comment: POSIX doesn't help by recognizing 4 different flavors itself (basic, extended, basic enhanced, and extended enhanced).

Comment: (My bad: the enhanced versions aren't actually POSIX.)